# How can I render a block in the sidebar in php?

Tags: theming

I'm using the Zen theme and I'm trying to keep as much in code as possible. I'm currently using context to render the block, but I like my php :)

I'm aware of

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'name_of_view_display');
print render($block);

// and this
$block = block_load('views', 'name_of_view-name_of_view_display');
$output = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
```

which works perfectly in most cases. My page.tpl file says

```
<?php if ($sidebar_first || $sidebar_second): ?>
  <aside class="sidebars">
    <?php print $sidebar_first; ?>
    <?php print $sidebar_second; ?>
  </aside>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, clearly, my $sidebar_second variable is empty. I tried to render the block in a theme_preprocess_page function, adding the block to the $vars['page']['sidebar_second'] array, but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assign block to region programmatically you can implement [hook_block_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7)

```
function YOURMODULE_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  if (isset($blocks['views']['name_of_view-name_of_view_display'])) {
    // assign block to region
    $blocks['views']['name_of_view-name_of_view_display']['region'] = 'sidebar_second';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could do it in the theme layer, but I guess not. That's one thing I like about Wordpress